# User Deprecated Functionality: Session ID is not used as URL parameter anymore

Tags: deprecated

i get the below error in magento

Exception #0 (Exception): User Deprecated Functionality: Session ID is not used as URL parameter anymore. in /var/www/html/magento.loc/vendor/magento/framework/Url.php on line 763

how can i resolve it? my php version is PHP 7.2.31-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: Please share your full magento version.

Comment: my magento version is 2.3.5-p1

Comment: Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No. Try and let me know. Also make sure you clean the cache & reindex.

Comment: @AbdulPathan in magento 2.3.5 we dont have SID on Storefront option anymore!

Comment: Yes, thats the reason I was assuming somewhere in your database use of SID is set to true. Something is calling addSessionParam() you need to debug full stack trace to see which method calls this function.

Comment: so whats your remedy to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi @Mahdi, My apologies I wont be able to give you exact solution without looking into logs. Hope you will understand. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi @Mahdi and other people,

If you have upgraded to Magento >=2.3.5 and one of your third party or custom extensions use one of the functions described above, you'll run into this issue.

In my case, I had previously installed the module veriteworks/cookiefix with the fixed version 1.0.6 (compatible with Magento < 2.3.5). This extension is used to fix the SameSite warnings in browsers. This version would use one of the deprecated functions related to the SID param.

You should look for extensions that use either for:

· **getSid** function, you can look for usages with:

```
grep -r "getSid(" vendor
grep -r "getSid(" app/code
```

· **addSessionParam** function:

```
grep -r 'addSessionParam()' vendor
grep -r 'addSessionParam()' app/code
```

If one of your extensions use these functions, you should remove it/update it/fix it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just tried that but only magento modules are showing up

vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolver.php:    public function getSid(SessionManagerInterface $session)
vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolverInterface.php:    public function getSid(\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session);


vendor/magento/framework/Url.php:    public function addSessionParam()
vendor/magento/framework/UrlInterface.php:    public function addSessionParam();

Comment: Hey Sander, feel free to contact me directly (twitter in my profile) if you want us to investigate together. I shared this solution because I had the same issue 2 days ago. Then we can share the solution here if we find it :)

Comment: Thanks, already found the error in my logs, it was caused by a third party module but did not show in the greps

Comment: One the extensions in my magento use the $sid = $this->sidResolver->getSid($this); How can I correct this?