# Magento 2.4.5 vendor folder Problem

Tags: magento2.4.5

Hello I have Magento 2 version 2.3.1 store which works as a marketplace using CES marketplace extension but after I upgrade my Magento 2 in to version 2.4.5.p1 and the marketplace extension start showing some bellow errors.
session id is not used as url parameter anymore. in /var/www/html/giftshop/vendor/magento/framework/url.php on line 769

is any one can help me on how to fix this error.
and also i've accidentaly deleted vendor/magento/framework/urlInterface.php and vendor/magento/framework/url.php file when try to fix the above error, can any body tell me how can i get that file back.
Thanks

Comment: Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/366700/82670

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the CES marketplace extension to a newer version that is compatible with Magento 2.4.5.p1

For the accidentally deleted files, you can restore them by re-downloading the Magento 2.4.5.p1 version and replacing the missing files in the vendor/magento/framework directory with the fresh copies.

It's always a good idea to make a backup before making any changes.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply, I've already checked the CES marketplace for the latest version of the extension. But there is no update in their system and the extension I've installed in my store is compatible with Magento 2.4.x but it still showing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**It still uses an older version of the function which is deprDeprecated Functionality in the new magento which is run on PHP 8 that's why it's showing this error.**

**Solution:** https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320656/82670

You should look for extensions that use either for:

> **getSid function, you can look for usages with:**

```
grep -r "getSid(" vendor
grep -r "getSid(" app/code
```

> **addSessionParam function:**

```
grep -r 'addSessionParam()' vendor
grep -r 'addSessionParam()' app/code
```

If one of your extensions use these functions, you should remove it/update it/fix it.